Jenkins Specifying Agent None In Seed Job
Our Jenkins setup is completely done using the configuration as code principle. There is a groovy setup script that creates a free style job that creates jobs from Groovy scripts checked into a repo. At the moment these jobs run on a node labelled system which is a label for the master/built-in Jenkins node. The gist of the script is as follows:
def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()

// Create the 'system/jobs' folder to hold these jobs.

def projectFolder = new Folder(jenkins, 'system')
projectFolder.save()
def jobsFolder = new Folder(projectFolder, 'jobs')
jobsFolder.save()

// Create the process jobs DSL build step.

def builder = new ExecuteDslScripts()
builder.setTargets('jobs/**/*.groovy')

// Create the import-build-jobs job.

def job = jobsFolder.createProject(FreeStyleProject, 'import-build-jobs')
job.addProperty \
    (new ParametersDefinitionProperty
         ([new StringParameterDefinition('Project',
                                         'cicdproj',
                                         'Git project'),
           new StringParameterDefinition('Repository',
                                         'seed-jobs',
                                         'Git repository'),
           new StringParameterDefinition('Branch',
                                         'origin/master',
                                         'Branch in repository')]))
job.scm = new GitSCM(GitSCM.createRepoList('ssh:....git', 'ssh-key'),
                     [new BranchSpec('origin/main')],
                     false,
                     null,
                     null,
                     null,
                     null)
job.setAssignedLabel(labels.LabelExpression.parseExpression('system'))   <- This is what want to change.
job.getBuildersList().add(builder)
job.save()

This works. However instead of in effect saying agent { label 'system' } I want to do agent none.
The reason is I am in the process of locking down our Jenkins instance so that the master node can't be used as a build node (i.e. executors = 0). As such any groovy, including pipelines, are still able to run on the master node but actual statements that require an agent like sh or bat can't. There are a number of seeded maintenance jobs written purely as standard Pipeline DSL that specify agent none and just execute as groovy on the master. However the above job is different as it needs to be created by running a script during initialisation.
How do I specify the equivalent of agent none in the above script? I have tried removing the above method call but it still tries to hunt around for a build agent, despite the fact that it doesn't need one.

Have you tried changing job.setAssignedLabel(labels.LabelExpression.parseExpression('system'))
to
job.setAssignedLabel(labels.LabelExpression.parseExpression('none')) ?
